Why can I no longer "direct" select an object in OBJECT MODE? I can no longer select the object I am trying to select with my cursor. Blender 4.0.2
I am new here.
Recently (a few days ago), if I want to select an object, the object I am trying to select is NOT selected. However, the largest object in line with the cursor is selected. NOTE: All objects are separate objects. I noticed that if I have multiple objects in line with my cursor and try to click on the smallest object, the largest object is selected. If I click again (without moving my cursor), the object next smaller object is selected. When I click again, the next smaller object is selected, and so on. As if each click is selecting from largest to smallest.
Did I hit a hot key by accident and change the way I make selections? The only way I can select the wanted object, I will need to keep clicking until my object is selected, or I will need to Alt-Click, and select the object from the drop-down list.

The only thing that you can change here is GPU Depth Picking in Selection section of Viewport settings in user preferences.
